# Как через бота отправить на телеграм-канал сообщение+ клавиатуру?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, telegram-bot

Не пойму, почему ошибку выдает

```
import telebot

token = '...'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

key = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
key.row('ex1')
key.row('ex2')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def sendtochannel(message):
  bot.send_message(chat_id='...' , text='lalala', reply_markup=key)

bot.polling()
```

Потом попробовал

```
def sendtochannel(message):
  bot.send_message(chat_id='...' , text='lalala')
  reply_markup=key
```

Но клавиатура появлялась в чате самого бота, а не на канале...

Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

при попытке отправить сообщение в канал с `types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()`:

> Bad Request: inline keyboard expected

а вот с inline клавиатурой всё работает. и в канал отправляется и callback отлавливается:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='123', callback_data='123')
    key.add(key_1)
    bot.send_message(-100...375, 'test text', reply_markup=key)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == '123':
        print('нажали 123 в канале')
```

Comment: @Nappy Says сработало?